# prove that $(ab+bc+ca)\bigg(\frac{a}{b(a^2+2b^2)}+\frac{b}{c(b^2+2c^2)}+\frac{c}{a(c^2+2a^2)}\bigg) \ge 3$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, sum-of-squares-method

> For $a, b, c$ positive reals prove that $$(ab+bc+ca)\bigg(\frac{a}{b(a^2+2b^2)}+\frac{b}{c(b^2+2c^2)}+\frac{c}{a(c^2+2a^2)}\bigg) \ge 3$$

I used the Cauchy-Swartz inequality in the LHS so I was left to prove that $\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+2b^2}}+\dfrac{b}{\sqrt{b^2+2c^2}}+\dfrac{c}{\sqrt{c^2+2a^2}} \ge \sqrt3$ but apparently for $(a,b,c)=(1,2,1)$ it is not correct.

Comment: Try manipulating the symmetries there. Changin (symbolically) a to b, b to c, and c to a leaves the expression unchanged. In the product, if an expression appears, then its counterparts via these switches also appears. See if you can find one term bigger than 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=\frac{1}{x}$, $b=\frac{1}{y}$ and $c=\frac{1}{z}$.

Hence, by Holder  $(ab+ac+bc)\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{c}{a(c^2+2a^2)}=(x+y+z)\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{x^2}{y(x^2+2z^2)}=$

$=(x+y+z)\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{x^3}{xy(x^2+2z^2)}\geq\frac{(x+y+z)^4}{3\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^3y+2x^2yz)}$.

Thus, it remains to prove that $(x+y+z)^4\geq9\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^3y+2x^2yz)$ or

$\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^4-5x^3y+4x^3z+6x^2y^2-6x^2yz)\geq0$ or

$\sum\limits_{cyc}(2x^4-x^3y-x^3z+12x^2y^2-12x^2yz)\geq9\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^3y-x^3z)$ or
$\sum\limits_{cyc}(x-y)^2(x^2+xy+y^2+6z^2)\geq9(x+y+z)(x-y)(x-z)(y-z)$.

Hence, it remains to prove the last inequality for $x\geq y\geq z$.
But $(x+y+z)(x-y)(x-z)(y-z)\leq(x+y)xy\Leftrightarrow z(x^2+y^2+xz-z^2)\geq0$, which is obvious.

Id est, it's enough to prove $(x+y+z)^4\geq9\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^3y+2x^2yz)$ for $z\rightarrow0$.

Let $x=ty$. Hence, we need to prove that $(t+1)^4\geq9t^3$, which is AM-GM:
$(t+1)^4=\left(3\cdot\frac{t}{3}+1\right)^4\geq\left(4\sqrt[4]{\frac{t^3}{27}}\right)^4>9t^3$.

Done!

Comment: could you elaborate on your first inequality? thank you.

Comment: Because of Holder's inequality it is true that $(1+1+1)(x+y+z)(\frac{x^3}{x^3y+2x^2yz}+\frac{y^3}{y^3z+2xy^2z}+\frac{z^3}{z^3x+2xyz^2})(x^3y+2x^2yz+y^3z+2xy^2z+z^3x+2xyz^2) \ge (x+y+z)^4$

Comment: In the fifth line, can we say that $\sum_{cyc}(6x^2y^2-6x^2yz) \ge 0$ according to Muirhead inequality since (2,2,0) majorizes (2,1,0), so that we are left to show that $\sum_{cyc}(x^4+4x^3z-5x^3y)\ge 0$ (if this is correct) ?

Comment: right! nice solution!